# IDA pseudocode: [var*size+ var + offset] to [structure pointer] format

Tags: ida

I'm trying to get the hang of IDA and I try to reverse engineer some code with a similar code [not 100% the same] to help me, I'm just using it to check.

The problem is that I came accros this issue:

[image]

How could I convert this into a friendlier pointer format ?
This blocks me because this is not using the classic BASE+OFFSET format plus it's using two variables...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May be this is what you are looking fir. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199403/differences-in-ollydbg-and-ida-pro-for-movsx-edx-byte-ptr-especx8-command/23604013#23604013

Comment: show the preceding code. how is `cur` initialized?